# Apache Storm writes sequentially numbers in Kafka-topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, stream-processing

I want to do some performance tests with kafka and storm. In my WordCount-test  a sequentially number is arriving in the "output"-topic:

```
uLK 1
1352 
GaE 1
1353
IGF 1
1354 
DtJ 2
1355 
MVy 1
...
```

It should be look like:

```
uLK 1
GaE 1
IGF 1
DtJ 2 
MVy 1
...
```

My storm-topology looks like follows:

```
builder.setSpout("kafkaSpoutPerfTest", kafkaSpout, 1);

builder.setBolt("split", new SplitSentence(), paralellismHint).shuffleGrouping("kafkaSpoutPerfTest");
builder.setBolt("count", new WordCount(), paralellismHint).fieldsGrouping("split", new Fields("message"));

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
props.put("acks", "0");
props.put("key.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
props.put("value.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

KafkaBolt kafkaBolt = new KafkaBolt()
                .withProducerProperties(props)
                .withTopicSelector(new DefaultTopicSelector("output"));

builder.setBolt("kafkaBoltOutput", kafkaBolt, 1).shuffleGrouping("count");
```

What am I doing wrong? Has somewone a clue? Thanks!